# Return to previous volume in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, howler.js

I am working on a volume slider where you can click the volume button and it will mute the audio, and when you hit the mute button it should return back to the previous audio setting. Here's my approach:

When volume button is clicked, it stores the bar width in the global variable `stored_volume` once it does this, it changes the volume setting to 0%. And displays the `muteBtn`

Now when the muteBtn is clicked, it should take that `stored_volume` variable and put it as the volume you want to go back to while also changing back to the volume icon

```
var stored_volume;

volumeBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {

    if (volumeBtn.style.display = 'block') {
        stored_volume = barFull.style.width;  
        alert(stored_volume);
    }

    Howler.volume(0);
    barFull.style.width = (0) + '%';
    volumeBtn.style.display = 'none';
    muteBtn.style.display = 'block';
});

muteBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {

    Howler.volume(stored_volume);
    barFull.style.width = (stored_volume) + '%';
    volumeBtn.style.display = 'block';
    muteBtn.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Here's my HTML

```
<div class="volume-container">
    <div class="media-btn" id="volumeBtn"></div>
    <div class="media-btn" id="muteBtn"></div>
    <div id="volume">
        <div id="barFull" class="bar"></div>
        <div id="barEmpty" class="bar"></div>
        <div id="sliderBtn"></div>
    </div>                   
</div>
```

`barFull` is the black overlay while `barEmpty` is the grey background color
[image: sorry for my poor paint skills]

sorry for my poor paint skills!

ISSUE: When I click the volume button, the volume drops to 0% but when I click the mute button to return to the previous value, it stays at 0%.

Comment: @azad hey sorry added the issue at the bottom of the question

Comment: also the alert displays nothing. This may be confusing but if I click volumeBtn > alert = blank > mutebtn > click and adjust volume to certain level > volumebtn > alert = that adjusted volume level

Comment: Possible to post a codepen ?

Comment: syntax error in your if statement `if (volumeBtn.style.display = 'block')` change to `if (volumeBtn.style.display == 'block')`

Comment: if (volumeBtn.style.display === 'block')

Comment: @azad & @Jeffin these provide the same output. It's interesting though because I don't receive an `alert()` the first time I click on the volumebtn but if I cycle through to click it again it displays `0%` like it's not storing the initial barwidth but after it goes to 0% on mute it will store that one..any thoughts?

Comment: what is value you get from alert?

Comment: @azad the first time I click the volume btn? No popup at all

Comment: you need to add your full code or demo code

Answer (score 0):

```
Howler.volume(parseInt(stored_volume));
```

try parsing the value you got from the measure of width, since it was a string the parameter you give to the `Howler.Volume()` is not being recognized as an appropriate value.

Comment: unfortunately no change here. Interestingly I posted this in the comment on my question, does this help you debug? I don't receive an alert() the first time I click on the volumebtn but if I cycle through to click it again it displays 0% like it's not storing the initial barwidth but after it goes to 0% on mute it will store that one..any thoughts?